# How to reverse a linked list while keeping the original linked list unchanged

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list

How can I reverse a linked list keeping original same?
If I am reversing the linked list it is changing the original one as well.

```
class Solution(object):
    def isPalindrome(self, head):
        """
        :type head: ListNode
        :rtype: bool
        """
        p = head
        q = self.reverse_list(head)
        
       
        while p and q:     
            if p.val != q.val:
                return False
            else:
                p = p.next
                q= q.next
        return True
            
        
    def reverse_list(self, head):
        curr = head
        prev = None
        while curr is not None:
            tmp = curr.next
            curr.next = prev
            prev = curr
            curr = tmp
            
        return prev
```

Comment: You need to adjust your concept of the change you want to make. You cannot reverse it and keep it the same. Perhaps you want to implement "duplicate list" first and then try "copy list in reverse"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a very aesthetically-pleasing (but not super efficient solution in python) using recursion. Basically, you can switch the order of recursions giving you a forward generator and a reverse generator, then zip and compare

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, head):
        return all(a.val == b.val 
                   for a,b 
                   in zip(self.forward(head), self.backward(head)))
            
    def forward(self, head):
        if head is None:
            return
        yield head
        yield from self.forward(head.next)


    def backward(self, head):
        if head is None:
            return 
        yield from self.backward(head.next)
        yield head
```

This is attractive, but unlikely to work with very large lists because of recursion limits.

For larger input you can make a non-recursive version of the `forward()` generator and render a list from it. Then compare the list to it's reverse:

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, head):
        v = list(self.forward(head))
        return v == v[::-1]
            
    def forward(self, head):
        while head:
            yield head.val
            head = head.next
```

This uses O(n) space, but should perform reasonably well.

Another solution would be to iterate through the list adding a `parent` property as you go. At the end you will have the tail of the list and can follow the parent reference in parallel to running the list from the head again and compare.